# (c# + windows forms) Adding items to listBox in different class

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two classes(forms), and I would like an item from `class2` to be added to `listBox` in `class1` when I click "Accept" button.

I tried with the following code, but nothing changes in the listBox:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarRental i = new CarRental();
    string id = idRental.Text.ToString();

    i.listBox1.Items.Add(id);
    i.listBox1.Update();
    this.Close();
}
```

Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Declare `RentalId` property on `Form2`. And at `CarRental` form (your first form) do following:

```
using(Form2 form2 = new Form2())
{
    if (fomr2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        return;

    listBox.Items.Add(form2.RentalId);
}
```

Implement `Fomr2.RentalId` property this way:

```
public string RentalId
{
   get { return idRental.Text; } // you don't need ToString() call
}
```

Then select your "Accept" button and set its `DialogResult` property to `OK`. Thus clicking on that button will close your dialog form and return `DialogResult.OK`.

Comment: Where excatly in form1 do i put that using{...}?

Comment: @cvenko this `using` shows Form2, so put it where you need to show Form2

Answer (score 0):

you created a new entity of type CarRental. what you should do is to send the first form to the second on construct, and modify things through that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the open form instead of creating new instance of CarRental form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarRental i = (CarRental)Application.OpenForms["CarRentalFormObjectName"];
    string id = idRental.Text.ToString();

    i.listBox1.Items.Add(id);
    i.listBox1.Update();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you pick just the first? or at least one?

Comment: What excatly do I need to put in ["CarRentalFormObjectName"]?