# Getting combobox value in to another form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, combobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(c# + windows forms) Adding items to listBox in different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439624/c-windows-forms-adding-items-to-listbox-in-different-class)

I want to get the combobox value in form1 and use it at form2, because the value will return another data from the registered user

```
public void povoacboxcliente()
{
    List<SM.BancoDados.BD.Model.Clientes> lstClientes = new List<SM.BancoDados.BD.Model.Clientes>();
    ClienteFlow flow = new ClienteFlow();

    lstClientes = flow.RetornaClientes();

    cboxCliente.DataSource = lstClientes;
    cboxCliente.DisplayMember = "Nome";
    cboxCliente.ValueMember = "Id";    
}
```

Now the value member (Id) will return the sex of the member, that is on database, this part is ok, but what I want is to do the operation in another form.. Here is the code that I'm trying on form2

```
public void enviasexo()
    {
        EnviarComando("0238373b3be503");
        idClient = Convert.ToInt32(cboxCliente.SelectedValue); 

        UsuarioFlow usuarioFlow = new UsuarioFlow();

        string combo = cboxCliente.SelectedValue.ToString();

        string sexo = usuarioFlow.RetornaSexo(combo);

        if (sexo == "M")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            EnviarComando("0232343b3bdc03");
            Thread.Sleep(200); //envia comando
        }
        else if (sexo == "F")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            EnviarComando("0232353b3bdd03");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
```

the "cboxCliente" was used in form1

Thanks People!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to make the ComboBox public in Form1.Designer.cs

then access the ComboBox from Form2

```
Form Form1Object = new Form1();
Form1Object.cboxCliente.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

See similar answer at

[Stack Overflow Answer for other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595381/823369)

Comment: what do you mean with Form1Object? Sry, I'm new to C#

Comment: To call a form from other Form, you have to create an instance of it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! sometimes I let pass basic things..hahaha

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation =/

Answer (score 0):

Please use one of  State management techniques which are available in Asp.Net when passing values in different forms.

see this
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management

**Client side state management techniques**

View State
Control State
Hidden fields
Cookies
Query Strings

**Server side state management techniques**

Application State
Session State

As a best practise form 2 should not be shown to user if one of the control value is strictly dependant on form 1...input from the user. apply page validation on form 2 and 
redirect user to form1 if the values from the drop down is not selected..

hope this helps
[shaz]